# unable to compile u-boot on windows 7 64-bit using cygwin, arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found

Tags: compilation, cygwin, 64-bit, u-boot

I am facing issue while compiling u-boot for OMAP-L1, I am using cygwin installed on a Windows 7 64-bit OS. when I run `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-`Cygwin says `make: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found` what I understood is that this error is because I am using a 64 bit machine and `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-` is an  32 bit application. to overcome this issue I need to install ia32-libs pkg. But I am not able to find this package under cygwin. Is there is any other way I can compile u-boot on a Windows 7 64-bit or is there any 64-bit arm cross compiler available.

PS. Before these command I used 
`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- distclean`
`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- omapl_xxx_config`

```
Me@MyMachine ~/u-boot-omapl1
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
make: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found
Generating include/autoconf.mk.dep
```

Comment: As far as I know, cross compilation toolchains such as arm-none-linux-gnueabi are not automatically included in most Linux distros and certainly not in Cygwin. You need to go to your processor supplier (in your case, TI), to download the toolchain. In the case of Cygwin, you may need to build the toolchain yourself. Personally, I'd recommend not using Cygwin. Run a standard Linux distro, such as Ubuntu, in a VM.